Where to ask questions about computer hardware?
What's the Stack Exchange site for asking hardware-related questions like server and desktop hardware, CPU and GPU hardware, cabling, and installation?


Where to ask questions about computer hardware?


https://superuser.com, e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-building
For hardware recommendations: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/


For hardware old enough to be of historical interest, there's also Retrocomputing.
